# IE crash on latest Java update 1.8.0u77 with jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, applet

recently we updated Java to latest version (1.8.0_77) and we discovered on IE, that this is causing stack overflow in Javascript, if there is a page rendered with an opened jQuery UI dialog.

Following code shows the problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <applet width="150" height="30"
            archive="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/examples/dist/applet_HelloWorld/applet_HelloWorld.jar"
            code="HelloWorld.class">
        <param name="initial_focus" value="false">
    </applet>
    <input id="password" type="password"/>
    <button id="login">Login</button>
</form>
<div id="dialog" title="Error">
    <p>Invalid password!</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#password').focus();
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $('#login').click(function () {
            console.log("Open dialog!!");
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In our tests it seems, that this is not happening on some previous Java version and also not on IE8 and IE9, but reproduces on IE10 and IE11.

When rendering this page, there are a lot of focusin and focusout events related to the button in the dialog and applet.
It looks, like although applet shouldn't gain focus, it does and then jQuery restores the focus on the button and then we have a loop.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?